# Why these two functions cannot be overloaded?

Tags: c++, overloading

Why i cannot overload these two functions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
    void run(int a);
    void run(const int a);
};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
prog.cpp:8:7: error: 'void Base::run(int)' cannot be overloaded
  void run(const int a);
       ^
prog.cpp:7:7: error: with 'void Base::run(int)'
  void run(int a);
```

Comment: How is the compiler going to decide if the `int` should be `const`?

Comment: Const and non-const isn't different

Comment: @EdHeal In a sense, it can (if the standard would say so, but it doesn't). E.g., treat the rvalues as true constants (as **it does** in case the of `const`/non-`const` references), and infere the constness of lvalues (after all, the compiler knows which lvalues are marked `const`). Are there any ambiguous situations that can appear otherwise? But this will complicate even much the overloading rules, which are already highly non-trivial.

Comment: @vsoftco The value is copied anyway, the constness of the argument has no bearing on the constness of the parameter. Unlike, say, a reference to non-const, where passing a const argument would be ill formed.

Comment: @Oktalist The fact that values are copied would not prevent the compiler from distinguishing `const` from `non-const`. In fact, in function definition compiler does it: `void f(const int a) { a = 0; }` is an error.

Comment: @AlexD Yes but here you are declaring a local parameter. The issue is when you pass the parameter, i.e. passing an `int` vs a `const int` to a 2 overloads taking `int` and `const int`, respectively. If the parameter is copied, it wouldn't make sense to try to distinguish what was passed, so probably that's the reason why the standard forbids such overloads. But again, technically I believe it can.

Comment: @vsoftco Sure, I understand the difference. I meant to say (as you did) that compiler _could distinguish_. If it makes sense or not is another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the standard:

> **13.1 Overloadable declarations**
> ....
>
> (3.4) — Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of `const` and/or `volatile` are
>   equivalent. That is, the `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when
>   determining which function is being declared, defined, or called. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
>    typedef const int cInt;
>    int f (int);
>    int f (const int); // redeclaration of f(int)
>    int f (int) { /* ... */ } // definition of f(int)
>    int f (cInt) { /* ... */ } // error: redefinition of f(int)
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]
>
> Only the `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers at the outermost level of the parameter type specification
>   are ignored in this fashion; `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers buried within a parameter type
>   specification are significant and can be used to distinguish overloaded function declarations. In
>   particular, for any type `T`, “pointer to `T`,” “pointer to `const T`,” and “pointer to `volatile T`” are
>   considered distinct parameter types, as are “reference to `T`,” “reference to `const T`,” and “reference to
>   `volatile T`.”

Comment: Yes `run(cont int&)` isn't equivalent to `run(int&)`.

Comment: as @juanchopanza says, when you take a references this quote doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yeah, I had to quote till the end, thanks!

Comment: @StefanMonov Correct, extended.